# The order of derivatives implies reversed order of minimizers

Tags: calculus, analysis, optimization, operations-research

> Suppose that $f_1$ and $f_2$ are both differentiable functions defined on $\mathbb{R}$ that have finite minimizers, $S_1$ and $S_2$, respectively, and that $f_1' \le f_2'$. Show that if $S_1$ and $S_2$ are unique minimizers, then $S_1 \ge S_2$.

I understand the "minimizers" to mean global minimizers. I tried showing it by contradiction: Suppose $S_1 < S_2$. Since $f_1(S_1)<f_1(S_2)$, $f_2(S_1)>f_2(S_2)$, if $f_1'$ and $f_2'$ are integrable, then $$0>f_2(S_2)-f_2(S_1) = \int_{S_1}^{S_2}f_2'(x)\textrm{d}x \ge \int_{S_1}^{S_2}f_1'(x)\textrm{d}x = f_1(S_2)-f_1(S_1)$$ contradicting that $f_1(S_1)<f_1(S_2)$. However, I don't know how to do the trick when the derivatives are not necessarily integrable. Could anyone please help me with this problem?

This problem is from Evan L. Porteus, *Foundations of Stochastic Inventory Theory*, p. 115.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem becomes more transparent if we write $g=f_2-f_1$ and restate the  claim as

> adding a nondecreasing function (namely, $g$) to $f_1$ cannot move the minimizer to the right.

Which is intuitively obvious, and easy to prove. We already have $f_1(x)>f_1(S_1)$ for all $x>S_1$. Adding $g$ preserves this: $$f_1(x)+g(x)>f_1(S_1)+g(S_1)\quad \text{  for all }x>S_1$$